# cwebp command remove meta data of image in converting

Tags: image-processing, exif, webp

I used cwebp for converting my images to webp with this command:

```
cwebp /Temp/Exmaple.jpg -o /Temp/Converted.webp
```

some of images captured with phone camera have meta data of orientation, in converting lost  this data and automatically rotated

this is one of image that rotated automatically:
[image]

test image in with [this online tools](https://www.imgonline.com.ua/eng/delete-exif.php) (Removing of EXIF and all other metadata from JPG image online) and image automatically rotated after removed metadata

in cwebp command, i used this flag `-metadata all` but not working and rotated again

i stucked in this, how can keeps metadata of images after converting to webp?

Comment: I removed the **ImageMagick** tag as that is not used in your question. You say you used `-metadata all` but that is not in the command you show? It is not clear what you actually want to achieve - do you want to remove all the metadata? Or retain all the metadata? Or just orient according to metadata then remove orientation? Try using `exiftool` to see what metadata you have before and then after doing whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you for your comment, i dont want to remove metadata, image automatic rotate 90 degree after removing metadata, i want transfer metadata from jpeg to webp (or rotate -90 after converting)